# Existential qualifier in z3 solver produces counterintuitive result

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using the Z3 solver to try to prove qualities of the domains of certain sets.  In this example, I am constructing two sets of ints. In pseudocode, it'd be...

```
a0 = x such that x < 5
a1 = x such that x < 6
```

I would like to construct the set of all possible sums of an element from `a0` and an element from `a1`.  Intuitively, I would think this would be:

```
a2 = x such that x < 10
```

I'm not sure exactly the best way to express `a2` in Z3, but the code below is clearly not one of them.  This test fails, but by my logic, it should pass. `Exists([v], And(a1[v], Not(a2[v])))` should produce an unsatisfactory result because there is no number in `a1` that is not in `a2`.  It would be helpful to know why the code below yields a satisfactory result and what that result would be.

```py
def test_set_inclusion_under_addition():
    a0 = Array('a0', IntSort(), BoolSort())
    a1 = Array('a1', IntSort(), BoolSort())
    a2 = Array('a2', IntSort(), BoolSort())
    x, y, a, m, n, v = Ints('x y a m n v')
    false, true = Bools('false true')
    s = Solver()
    s.add(false == False)
    s.add(true == True)
    s.add(a0 == Lambda([m], If(m < 5, true, false)))
    s.add(a1 == Lambda([n], If(n < 6, true, false)))
    s.add(a2 ==
        Lambda([x],
            If(Exists([a],
                And(a0[a],
                a1[x - a])),
            true,
            false)))
    s.add(Exists([v], And(a1[v], Not(a2[v]))))
    assert s.check() == unsat
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're saying your test is failing. When I run it, it successfully produces `unsat` for the `check` call.

Perhaps you're using an old version of z3? There were some recent changes to how `Lambda` constructs are processed. Can you try with a fresh build from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/tag/Nightly? Or better yet, build it directly from the sources.

Comment: Could also be platform-dependent (I'm on windows). I'm using version `4.8.5.0`. I'll try to build from source!

Comment: I hope it's not because of the platform! I'm pretty sure a recent source compile will fix this issue, but do report back if that's not the case.